# Flurry new users count

Tags: ios, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have integrated Flurry Analytics into my iOS app. I haven't released the app yet so there can't be any real users except for myself. However, the second day I found that Flurry reports there are 5 new users. How is that possible? I did delete and rebuild my app to my phone several times for testing purpose, but according to Flurry FAQ, the same device should only be counted once. Does rebuild app from Xcode change the device id? or the hashing function of the device id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flurry relies on IDFV for metrics purposes.  In the event that you uninstall the app and have no other apps on that device from that developer (meaning you), then the device will register as a new user.

On top of this, when submitting for distribution, Apple seems to run some automatic analysis on the app.  This typically results in around 10 to 20 new users, though this effect is only observable in small apps.

Comment: Is there a way to track and get the accurate number of users?

Comment: Define "user". In our parlance, a "user" is a known device. If someone clears a device, then that device is a new "user". You, on your side, can log a user ID, but that isn't necessarily reflected in our metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the same thing, I was developing with 3 devices yet according to their stats I had dozens and dozens of unique users. I wrote and politely asked what was going on and would they offer an explanation, they couldn't be bothered to reply. Same thing happened after releasing the app to the app store - the app registers with my server so I know how many users there are, yet the number reported by flurry versus the actual number differed by a huge amount. So I've come to the conclusion their figures are total bullshit.

If there's somebody from Flurry reading this please feel free to refute this and offer an explanation, if you can.

Comment: I found that the deviceToken observed in iOS is different every time. I think that might be why Flurry get confused. I'm talking about ios9. Not sure whether it has been always like that or is it something new.

Comment: My observations of this behavior with Flurry date back to iOS 7 and 8.